# How to access the angular application route with parameter from another application

Tags: angular, routes

I have a requirement where One application will have a link and on the click of that link I need to open a angular application with query parameter in the URL.

something like this
`https://myapplicationdomain.com/search/12345678`

I have a default route which is `/search` so wherever the application loads it goes to search route and there I am using parameter to search.

this is not working because when I click on the URL its not loading the application with `https://myapplicationdomain.com/search/12345678` and says **Page not found**

What configuration I need to do to make this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your webserver correctly, so it will correctly serve your applications.
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples - check everything here!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Do I need to add an .htaccess file to angular code ir I need to directly add that to server?

Comment: create a .htaccess file on the root of your shared Apache server
don't forget to restart your server